# Limit a single record in model for django app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to use a model to save the system setting for a django app. So, I want to limit the model so it can only have one record. How to do the limit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An easy way is to use the setting's name as the primary key in the settings table. There can't be more than one record with the same primary key, so that will allow both Django and the database to guarantee integrity.

Comment: This is the most correct answer. The other suggestions only affect the admin, but this will address any time an object is saved. The name doesn't need to be primary, however, just unique.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    onefield = models.CharField('The field', max_length=100)

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  def has_add_permission(self, request):
    # if there's already an entry, do not allow adding
    count = MyModel.objects.all().count()
    if count == 0:
      return True

    return False
```

Answer (score 13):

William is right, but I guess this is the best practice

```
def has_add_permission(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return not MyModel.objects.exists()
```

As reported in the official Django Documentation:

> Note: Don’t use this if all you want to do is determine if at least one result exists.
>   It’s more efficient to use exists().

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Answer (score 10):

Overwriting `has_add_permission` works, but in the given examples it breaks the permissions system in Django(staff without necessary permissions can add settings). Here's a one that doesn't break it:

```
class SettingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        base_add_permission = super(SettingAdmin, self).has_add_permission(request)
        if base_add_permission:
            # if there's already an entry, do not allow adding
            count = Setting.objects.all().count()
            if count == 0:
                return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 3):

A model with a single allowed row is nothing more than a perverted form of a "persisted object" -- maybe even a "persisted singleton"?  Don't do that, that's not how models work.

Check out https://github.com/danielroseman/django-dbsettings

Comment: After digging around a bit https://github.com/praekelt/django-preferences looks a bit more promising (django-dbsettings was last updated 10 years ago).

Comment: Could also consider this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3868969/5506400

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Ali Reza's answer but you can update the existed records and return the error message to any form that uses this model. I believe it is reliable and much easy to control.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        if not self.id and MyModel.objects.exists():
            raise ValidationError('You cannot add more somethings.')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a class I have created which can be used as a singleton class.

```
from django.db import models
class SingletonModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__class__.objects.exclude(id=self.id).delete()
        super(SingletonModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def load(cls):
        try:
            return cls.objects.get()
        except cls.DoesNotExist:
            return cls()
```

From the above `SingletonModel` we can create multiple models, all of which will be having only one record

```
class ProjectSettings(SingletonModel):
    max_tickets = models.IntegerField(default=15)
    min_tickets = models.IntegerField(default=2)
    ...
```

We can access the only object of the settings model as follows

```
ProjectSettings.load().max_tickets
```

It is also possible to register `ProjectSettings` to django admin

```
@admin.register(ProjectSettings)
class ProjectSettingsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [field.name for field in ProjectSettings._meta.get_fields()]
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        # Nobody is allowed to delete
        return False
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can rewrite the save method on your model. Whenever the user wants to register a new record, you can check the existence then, either save the record or, reject the request.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    body = models.TextField(...)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if MyModel.objects.exists():
            raise ValueError("This model has already its record.")
        else:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can also use [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/). I prefer to use this method.
Hope you find it useful.

Comment: it's restricting to edit the already available records

Comment: All the way true. Thanks. Doesn't work if u try to edit the existing record.

Comment: But Ali, the question was about to limit the only 1 record, not the existing one.