# Django admin site: how to create a single page for global settings?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-forms

I would like to create a single page in the admin site of django where I can change some global variables of the website (title of the website, items in the navigation menu, etc). At the moment I have them coded as context processors but I would like to make them editable. Something similar to what happens in WordPress.

Is this possible?

- I can store the data in the databse, but can I have a link in the admin site that goes straight to the first document record and doesnt allow the creation of multiple records (they wouldnt make sense)
- Instead of creating a model in the database, would it be possible to change some context_processor from the admin site (I think this would be best)

Answer (score 5):

[django-preferences](http://github.com/praekelt/django-preferences) does exactly what you are looking for. The implementation is a bit hacky (particularly the setting of `__module__` on the model class to trick Django into thinking it was loaded from a different app), but it works.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply! looks awesome but I can't get it working... I put the package in the my site-packages folder and then added the 'preferences' to the INSTALLED_APP and the (r'^admin/', include('preferences.urls')), to the urls.py. I tried to create a simple module like the one suggested but I run into an error when I try to import the class 'from preferences.model import Preferences' as it says it can't find the Preferences module. Any idea? Im still not very good with Django... THANKS

Comment: I think there's a typo in the README. It should be "from preferences.models import Preferences" - note the plural "models."

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like what the sites framework is intended to help with.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/sites/

"It’s a hook for associating objects and functionality to particular Web sites, and it’s a holding place for the domain names and “verbose” names of your Django-powered sites."

The docs make it sound like it's only good for multiple sites, but it's a great place to put stuff in a single-site-per-django model too.

Comment: If even caches the values for you, which is great, but if you have multiple workers, you will need to call `Site.objects.clear_cache()` after changes so all workers get the changes.

Answer (score 2):

There's an app called [django-values](https://code.google.com/p/django-values/) that allows you storing of specific settings in the database.