# Customized Settings in Django

Tags: django

I am creating an electronic reference library for my school, where I have created a custom admin page (not the Django admin page). And in my requirements there needs to be a specific 'settings' page where I can store small information such as

- How frequently to create reports
- How frequently users should change their passwords etc.

These kinds of custom settings are not available in Django by default. But is there a way I can implement it in my app? And how should I store this information? Should I create another table to store these information?

Please let me know how to tackle such a situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the best way would probably be just to create another table for your settings.
That is because:

a. Django provides good tools for DB management, so it is less to worry about the infra.

b. You will usually have a DB access. You cannot say the same about other resources, depends on your server.

Just do something like this:

Then you may want to ensure somehow you only have one record, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106823/limit-a-single-record-in-model-for-django-app) for example.

```
class MySettings(models.Model):
    setting1 = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    setting2 = models.IntegerField(default=11)
```

There are alternatives, of course, for example creating a simple dict containing your settings, and add some methods to serialize it to the local disc, in a well known location. Something like this:

```
import json

MY_SETTINGS_LOCATION = "/path/to/my/settings.json"

def load_settings() {
    with open(MY_SETTINGS_LOCATION, "r") as f:
        return json.load(f)
}

def save_settings(settings) {
    with open(MY_SETTINGS_LOCATION, "w") as f:
        return json.dump(settings, f)
}
```